# Zariski tangent space to a moduli space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, moduli-space

I’m reading the paper [*13/2 Ways of Counting Curves*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1111.1552) by Pandharipande and Thomas. I’m very confused with the following statement on page 8

> $\S$ **Deformation theory.** We return now to the deformation theory for embedded curves briefly discussed in Section $\frac{1}{2}$. The deformation theory for arbitrary stable maps is very similar.
>
> Let $C \subset X$ be a nonsingular embedded curve with normal bundle $\nu_C$. The Zariski tangent space to the moduli space $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_g(X,\beta)$ at the point $[C \to X]$ is given by $H^0(C, \nu_C)$. Locally, we can lift a section of $\nu_C$ to a section of $T_X |_C$ and deform $C$ along the lift to first order. Since globally $\nu_C$ is not usually a summand of $T_X|_C$ but only a quotient, the lifts will differ over overlaps by vector fields along $C$. The deformed curve will have a complex structure whose transition functions differ by these vector fields. In other words, from
>
> $$0 \to T_C \to T_X |_C \to \nu_C \to 0$$
>
> we obtain the sequence
>
> $$(1.1) \quad 0 \to H^0(C, T_C) \to H^0(C, T_X |_C) \to H^0(C, \nu_C) \to H^1(C, T_C)$$

How do I understand the Zariski tangent space? Many thanks!

Comment: Do you mean "how do I understand the Zariski tangent space in this context" or the broader "how do I understand the Zariski tangent space in general"? (It would also be good for you to write the math out in MathJax and add a little more complete citation to your text.)

Comment: Welcome to mse! I've edited your question to use mathjax (which is searchable) rather than an image (which isn't), as well as to link to the paper you reference. This is so that future users will have an easier time finding this question and your linked paper. In the future you should do the same ^_^

Comment: That looks way much better! Thank you both!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say that our moduli space $\mathcal{M}$ is a scheme. In that case, for a given point $x\in \mathcal{M}$, the Zariski tangent space $T_{x}\mathcal{M}$ is the usual tangent space, i.e. given by $(\mathfrak{m}_x/\mathfrak{m}_x^2)^\vee$, where $\mathfrak{m}_x$ is the unique maximal ideal of the local ring $\mathcal{O}_{\mathcal{M},x}$. The tangent directions to $x$ represent first order deformations of $x$ in the ambient space, $\mathcal{M}$.

The authors are making the claim that there is a canonical identification of vector spaces between the tangent space to $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_g(X;\beta)$ at the point $[C\to X]$ and $H^0(C,\nu_C)$. The intuition for this is as follows: if we consider deforming a single point $x\in X$ to first order in $X$, we consider an element of $T_x X$. In the case that we are deforming a family of points (e.g. a curve $C$ in $X$), we should choose a vector at each point $x\in C$. This gives us a vector field along $C$, i.e. an element of $H^0(C,T_X|_C)$. However, to ensure we are actually deforming into the ambient directions (as opposed to defining a vector field which flows the curve into itself), we should really consider vector fields that point outwards from $C$. That is, we should consider elements of $H^0(C,\nu_C)$.

This is not a proof, but at least gives some intuition for this idea.

Also, a technical comment. In this case, $\overline{\mathcal{M}}_g(X;\beta)$ should really be a (Deligne-Mumford) stack. There is a functorial definition of the Zariski tangent space in terms of maps
$$\mathrm{Spec}\:k[\epsilon]/(\epsilon^2) \to \overline{\mathcal{M}}_g(X;\beta)$$
better suited to this case. For this, you can see Definition 3.5.7 of [Alper](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Ejarod/moduli.pdf) (n.b. the numbering may change as the text is updated often).

Comment: This makes it much clearer. Thank you Alekos!